# Formatting expressions with numeric exponents using pattern matching

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, output-formatting

Thank you all in advance.

Question:
I want to change the format of this expression `(n + r)^3/n^3` into this `(1+r/n)^3`using rules an patterns.

I manage to work this with symbolic exponents. In this example `q`:

```
(n + r)^q/n^q /. (n + r)^q_/n^q_ -> HoldForm[(1 + r/n)^q](*This works with symbolic exp*)
```

But if I change exponent `q` for any number, it won't work any longer.

```
(n + r)^3/n^3 /. (n + r)^q_/n^q_ -> HoldForm[(1 + r/n)^q] (*This does not work with numeric exp*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
expr1 = (n + r)^q/n^q
r1 = (n_ + r_)^q_  -> n^q (1 + r/n)^q
expr2 = expr1 /. r1
```

$$\left(\frac{r}{n}+1\right)^q$$

```
(n + r)^3/n^3 /. r1
```

$$\left(\frac{r}{n}+1\right)^3$$

Comment: Thank you Syed. Your method works. I am studying it. But, why doesn't the substitution I tried work with numbers?

Comment: `why doesn't the substitution I tried work with numbers?` because Mathematica automatically modify/simplify the expression when q is a number vs. symbol.  See the difference printed after writing `(n+r)^q/n^q` and then `q=3; (n+r)^q/n^q`. Do you know see why? Look at the FullForm of each also to see the difference.

Comment: @Sanmuten : Nasser has already described why. Another way of thinking about it is that if you are asking Mma to expand `(a+b)^n`. How can it do so, if `n` is not an integer? As soon as you provide it `n=3`, it simplifies and gets to cancel the denominator.